# Why the console is printing multiple value how to fix it it should be print once

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
loadbyGroup(1);
    $('.by-seller').click(function(){       
    loadbyGroup(2);
  });
  $('.by-users').click(function(){        
    loadbyGroup(1);
  });
  function loadbyGroup(val){ 
    var tempo_array = [{'data':[]}];
    $('.test').click(function(){
        console.log(tempo_array)
    });
    //some if else condition below val == 1 or 2 not necessary
  }
```

});

When i click the button '.by-users' and click the .test button it's printing multiple value '[{'data':[]}]' in console log and this is my problem it should be print once just like the first load of the page when you click .test button how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding multiple click handlers on button test on each execution of loadbyGroup() call, so remove it out of loadbyGroup function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var tempo_array = [];

    loadbyGroup(1);

    $('.by-seller').click(function(){       
        loadbyGroup(2);
    });

    $('.by-users').click(function(){        
        loadbyGroup(1);
    });

    $('.test').click(function(){
        console.log(tempo_array)
    });

    function loadbyGroup(val){ 
        tempo_array = [{'data':[]}]; // or whatever you want to do with this array
    }
});
```